# What happens when I remove a device from my Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, microsoft-account

I have a Win 10 tablet that I want to send out for repair but technical support asks me for the account password. This password is my Microsoft account with a lot of services and I will not disclose it.

**Is there a way to disconnect or reset the account to a local one remotely?** Because I can not access the tablet anymore, the thing I want to be repaired is the power button...

So, I was checking and I can remove the device from my Microsoft Account remotely. **What would happen if I do so? The tablet wouldn't be password protected anymore? Or the last local account would be activated? Or something else?**

Comment: You no longer sync your settings, you have to authorize the device to access your account in the future, and you lose Cortana and Windows Hello functions

Comment: Tell them to enable the built-in Administrator.  Even if you disconnect your device from the account until you covert it back to a local account you would have to give them your MS to access your account.  If they don't know how to do that don't send it to them send they know nothing about computers if that's the case